# How to horizontal scroll for ngInfiniteScroll?

Tags: angularjs, nginfinitescroll

currently ngInfiniteScroll is anbled for vertical-scrolling, but I need it on horizontal scroll.

I am displaying data under ng-repeat in a table with horizontal scroll. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MdcZ.jpg)

Comment: any solution for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the property "horizontal" to true, by default is false. You can check this page:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-infinite-scroll